# Javascript generation of SVG

Tags: javascript, svg

I have drawn a complex path in my browser (Firefox) as a background, using Javascript-generated SVG elements and attributes, and would like to superimpose icons that consist of multiple SVG shapes.  In the example below, the shape is not being drawn.  Can anyone spot my error?

```
function mygui() {
    var xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
    var boxWidth = 2188;
    var boxHeight = 1312;

    var svgElem = document.createElementNS (xmlns, "svg");
    svgElem.setAttributeNS (null, "viewBox", "0 0 " + boxWidth + " " + boxHeight);
    svgElem.setAttributeNS (null, "width", boxWidth);
    svgElem.setAttributeNS (null, "height", boxHeight);
    svgElem.setAttributeNS (null, "preserveAspectRatio", "xMidYMid meet");

    var g = document.createElementNS (xmlns, "g");
    svgElem.appendChild (g);
    g.setAttributeNS (null, "transform", "translate(0.000000,1312.000000) scale(0.100000,-0.100000)");

    var coords = ... //I have a very long list of coordinates here

    var path = document.createElementNS (xmlns, "path");
    path.setAttributeNS (null, "d", coords);
    path.setAttributeNS (null, "fill", "black");
    g.appendChild (path);

    //Everything above this point is displayed correctly

    var icon = document.createElementNS (xmlns, "g");
    icon.setAttributeNS (null, "id", "1");
    svgElem.appendChild (icon);

    var subicon = document.createElementNS (xmlns, "circle");
    subicon.setAttributeNS (null, "fill", "beige");
    subicon.setAttributeNS (null, "stroke", "orange");
    subicon.setAttributeNS (null, "stroke-width", "20");
    subicon.setAttributeNS (null, "cx", "13000");
    subicon.setAttributeNS (null, "cy", "8000");
    subicon.setAttributeNS (null, "r", "60");
    icon.appendChild (subicon);

    //I will have more sub-icons, but use only one here

    var svgContainer = document.getElementById ("svgContainer");
    svgContainer.appendChild (svgElem);

}
```

Comment: Are there any errors in your browser console?

Comment: id values may not be numeric, although that would not cause rendering to fail it would possibly make the `<g>` element non-referenceable.

Comment: I changed id to alphanumeric, and corrected one console warning about the charset not being specified in the HTML document.  I still do not see the circle.

Comment: maybe append subicon to icon and then icon to the svg?

Comment: That does seem cleaner, and parallels a static SVG document, but did not solve the problem.

Comment: Whoops.  I meant static SVG element.

Comment: I think it is only a dimensional issue ... http://jsfiddle.net/jzhb6woz/ that works. I got nothing at first. I thik your cx, cy is incorrect (8000, 13000)? W

Comment: Confirmed, you are drawing it outside the viewing area at 13000,8000. http://jsfiddle.net/jzhb6woz/1/ moving it to 100,100

Comment: You are correct about the cx and cy.  Those coordinates worked in a static SVG file, but I do not recall how I came up with them.  Thanks!

Comment: OK, then are you going to accept the answer then or ?

Comment: Yes, sorry, this is my first time.  I do not see how to mark the question as answered.  Thanks very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

1) You have to add the subicon to the icon before adding the icon to the svgElem.

2) The location of the circle center cx,cy is way outside the drawing

See code or fiddle below, i moved the circle inside the drawing area and moved the order of building the icon. The remainder of the code I left out as it as you say was functional.

See http://jsfiddle.net/jzhb6woz/1/

```
function mygui() {
var xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
var boxWidth = 2188;
var boxHeight = 1312;

var svgElem = document.createElementNS (xmlns, "svg");
svgElem.setAttributeNS (null, "viewBox", "0 0 " + boxWidth + " " + boxHeight);
svgElem.setAttributeNS (null, "width", boxWidth);
svgElem.setAttributeNS (null, "height", boxHeight);
svgElem.setAttributeNS (null, "preserveAspectRatio", "xMidYMid meet");


//Everything above this point is displayed correctly

var icon = document.createElementNS (xmlns, "g");
icon.setAttributeNS (null, "id", "1");


var subicon = document.createElementNS (xmlns, "circle");
subicon.setAttributeNS (null, "fill", "beige");
subicon.setAttributeNS (null, "stroke", "orange");
subicon.setAttributeNS (null, "stroke-width", "20");
subicon.setAttributeNS (null, "cx", "100");
subicon.setAttributeNS (null, "cy", "100");
subicon.setAttributeNS (null, "r", "60");
icon.appendChild (subicon);
svgElem.appendChild (icon);

//I will have more sub-icons, but use only one here

var svgContainer = document.getElementById ("svgContainer");
svgContainer.appendChild (svgElem);
}
```